# Select from multiple lists

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have the following Linq query:

```
    var identities = message.Events
        .Where(x => x.EventType == eventType)
        .Where(x => x.Roles?.Any(y => y.RoleId == 42) == true)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Roles, (parent, child) =>
            new
            {
                parent.Id,
                child.CustomerName,
                child.CustomerNumber,
                child.RegionId

            })
        .Select(x =>
            new AuditFirmEmployeeCrud(x.CustomerName, x.CustomerNumber.Value, x.RegionId, x.GlobalId));
```

In the Events-list, I have another List, IEnumerable, that I want to get data from as well:

```
  public class MetaData
  {
    string Key { get; set; }

    string Source { get; set; }

    string Value { get; set; }
  }
```

But I don't know how to select from multiple lists. I would like to try to combine SelectMany on x.Roles and x.MetaData in some way.

Here is the lists:

```
public class EventList
{
    Event[] Events {get; set;}
}

public class Event
{
    EventType Type {get; set;}
    Guid Id {get; set;}
    IEnumerable<Accounts>? Accounts { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<MetaData>? Metadata { get; set; } // This i want to combine as well, and get the value of the Key and Value property

    IEnumerable<Roles>? Roles { get; set; } // This I already got
}
```

So basically, I want to re-write this to Linq:

```
    foreach (var eventRow in message.Events)
    {
        if (eventRow.EventType == someEvent)
        {
            var Id = eventRow.GlobalId;
            var customerNumber = eventRow.Roles.Where(x => x.RoleId == 42).Select(x => x.CustomerNumber).FirstOrDefault();
            var regionId = eventRow.Roles.Select(x => x.RegionId).FirstOrDefault();
            var customerName = eventRow.Metadata.Select(x => x.Key + " " + x.Value).FirstOrDefault();

            var crudObj = new AuditFirmEmployeeCrud(customerName, customerNumber.Value, regionId, Id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Yes? Look in my question how the MetaData-class is defined. It's three properties in the MetaData-class, and I want to get the value of the Value Property and the Key property.

Comment: Obviously I don't get it. I'm out

Comment: @ThomasWeller: Check my updated question again. :)

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault()` - That makes it just 1 value instead of a list

Comment: @ThomasWeller: The child lists will only contain one row. Can you help me or not to re-rewrite the foreach to a linq expression instead?

Comment: Sorry, IMHO the new code does not make sense. `class Event` does not have a property `EventType` and `eventRow` does not have a property `GlobalId`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I give up. Im out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand what the problem is. Your question is confusing because the LINQ query at the beginning of your question has little to do with what you are doing in the foreach loop at the end of the question.

Do you really just want to convert the foreach loop into LINQ? If so, that's pretty straightforward:

```
var identities = message.Events
    .Where(eventRow => eventRow.EventType == someEvent)
    .Select(eventRow => new
    {
        Id = eventRow.GlobalId,
        CustomerNumber = eventRow.Roles
            .Where(x => x.RoleId == 42)
            .Select(x => x.CustomerNumber)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        RegionId = eventRow.Roles
            .Select(x => x.RegionId)
            .FirstOrDefault(),
        CustomerName = eventRow.Metadata
            .Select(x => x.Key + " " + x.Value)
            .FirstOrDefault()
    })
    .Select(x => new AuditFirmEmployeeCrud(x.CustomerName, x.CustomerNumber.Value, x.RegionId, x.Id))
    .ToArray();
```